# Receiving "No such file or directory" in pyspark2.3 in regards to PYSPARK_PYTHON python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, emr

We've started a new spark cluster on EMR that is running Spark 2.3.0, and are trying to run the same command as on a cluster running Spark 2.2.0, but we are getting the traceback: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./venv/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory`.

The command that we are running is:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python 
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --py-files=dist/project_main-1.0.0- 
py2.7.egg --master=yarn --deploy-mode=client --archives=venv.zip#venv - 
-packages org.apache.derby:derbytools:10.14.1.0,org.apache.derby:derbyclient:10.14.1.0,com.github.databricks:spark-avro:204864b6cf,com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:3.0.0-preview1,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0,com.amazon.redshift:redshift-jdbc42:1.2.12.1017 --repositories https://jitpack.io,http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release --executor-memory 4g project_main/main.py
```

We've ensured that the virtualenv is relocatable, and have tried different combinations of `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, `--archives`, and `--files` within the spark submit command. We tried omitting `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, but it was not running inside the virtualenv, and were missing our packages and libraries.

Has the behavior of `PYSPARK_PYTHON` or `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` or `--archives` changed from 2.2 to 2.3?

Comment: how did you fix this? thanks